# SQL Server FileStreamSize

Tags: sql-server-2008

Code doesn't return FileStreamSize

```
with fs as
(
    select database_id, type, size * 8.0 / 1024 size
    from sys.master_files
)
select 
    Cast(db.database_id As int ) DbId,
    name,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 0 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) DataFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 1 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) LogFileSizeMB,
    (select sum(size) from fs where type = 2 and fs.database_id = db.database_id) FileStreamSizeMB
from sys.databases db    
order by DbId
```

The DataFileSizeMB and LogFileSizeMB return correct size in MB but  FileStreamSizeMB return 0 when I checked the databases the actual  FileStreamSize is not a 0.

Thank you for help. :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of [sys.master_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-master-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) dmv clearly states for `size` column:

> Note: This field is populated as zero for FILESTREAM containers. Query the sys.database_files catalog view for the actual size of FILESTREAM containers.

So in this case you need to query [sys.database_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-files-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but you can do this only in the context of it's database (or by fully qualifying the name as `database_name.sys.database_files`).

The FILESTREAM data doesn't reside in the filegroup container, but on the file system. You could reconsider the reasons behind your query and decide do you actually need to know the "size" of this container. If you really need this, then you could build some solution using [sp_foreachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) and query each database for the size of the containers.